# How to display Partial view Model errors when partial view is in the view?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, partial-views

I am working on the Asp.net Core 2.0 project and have a `partial view` that is shown in the `index` view. This `partial view` have a Model with some validation errors.

You can continue to see my Model,Partial view,controller and ...

**LoginViewModel**

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "UserName")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Please Enter UserName")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember Me")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

I have used `LoginViewModel` as `model` in `_loginpartialView`. also there are `asp-validation-for` to show validation error after each `input`

**_loginpartialView.cshtml**

```
@model partialView.Models.LoginViewModel

    <div id="login">
        <span class="header-lastnews">Login</span>
        <div class="hr"></div>

        <form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" method="post">


            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="UserName" class="col-sm-4 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input asp-for="UserName" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Password" class="col-sm-4 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label asp-for="RememberMe">
                            <input asp-for="RememberMe" />
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row" style="width: 100%">
                <div class="form-group pull-left ">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Enter</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

I have used `@Html.Partial` to render and show `partial view` in `index`
Be careful that the `index` view is inside the `HomeController`

**Index.cshtml**

```
@{
     ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

@Html.Partial("_loginpartialView")
```

And at the end this is my `AccountController`

**AccountController**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Success Login
            //do Something
        }
        else
        {
            //if ModelState is invalid
            return PartialView("_loginpartialView", model);
        }

        //if UserName Or Password is incorrect
        return PartialView("_loginpartialView", model);
    }
```

But the problem is that when I click on the `submit` button without entering the inputs value, a new page opens and `partial view` and Model errors show on new page. 
How can i show model errors in `partial view` in the same view not a new page?

Comment: Sounds like you need to use AJAX POST instead of standard form posting to return partial view inside main view when validation errors occurred (`<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" method="post">` creates standard POST form, not AJAX one).

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto could you please introduce me good tutorial or sample code?

Comment: Try adding `data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#formID"` to your partial view's form (and you should use form ID to update the form content).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a standard form submission tag, which sends POST request and returns new page as expected response:

```
<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" method="post">
```

Since you want to return partial view into same page with validation errors, you must use AJAX-based form. You can convert standard form submit like above into AJAX-based form which returns partial view at the same main view, as in example below:

```
<form id="partialform" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-update="#partialform" data-ajax-mode="replace">
    <!-- form inner elements here -->
</form>
```

The most important things you should remember:

1. `data-ajax="true"` must be exist to ensure form accepts AJAX data.
2. Setting `id` attribute and provide that ID value to `data-ajax-update` property so that the jQuery selector behind AJAX callback recognizes it.
3. `data-ajax-mode="replace"` set to replace previous form element together with its inner elements after AJAX `success` result to response from server.

**Note:** The form inner element replacement with `data-ajax-mode="replace"` is done by `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script which runs in background.

Comment: This AJAX form isn't create a new partial, it just replace existing partial view with new response acquired from server.