# Asp.net Core, redirect to another view from partial view using form ajax?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, partial-views, ajaxform

I have a `Partial view` that contains a `form ajax` in Asp.net core 2.0.

You can see `Partial View` named `_loginPartial`

```
@model partialView.Models.LoginViewModel

<div id="login">
<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" id="frmLogin" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-update="#frmLogin" data-ajax-mode="Replace">
    <div id="login">

        <div class="form-group">
            <input asp-for="UserName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="UserName"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="UserName"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group pull-left ">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

When i submit form to `/Account/Login` everything is ok, but after login i want to redirect to another view in another `Area`

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Success Login
            return Redirect("/AdminPanel/Home/Index");
        }
        else
        {
            //if ModelState is invalid

        }

        //if UserName Or Password is incorrect
        return PartialView("_loginpartialView", model);
    }
```

And here is `LoginViewModel`

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "UserName")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Please Enter UserName")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }


}
```

Also i use this code to Show `Partial View` in `index`

```
  @Html.Partial("_loginpartialView")
```

But there is a problem. After success login new view replace with `Partial view`.In other words, it does not navigate to `/AdminPanel/Home/Index` and new `View` replace with `Partial View`, How can i navigate to another view in this case?

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to stay in the **same** page! If you want to redirect, do not use ajax. Make a normal submit.

Comment: @StephenMuecke But with normal submit cant show model errors if `ModelState` not valid in partial view

Comment: @StephenMuecke I disagree. This one doesn't seem an SPA so it could be ok to reload the page when there are many changes. I think a login could fall into that category.

Comment: @AdamSimon, Read the question - OP wants to redirect - it is utterly pointless (and degrading performance) to use ajax

Comment: @saeed, If you have `ModelState` errors, then you return the view so they are displayed (and you should be including the elements to display your validation errors)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Looking at the controller code, I'd say OP wants to redirect _when the login succeed_. Otherwise he wants a partial update displaying an error. Not necessarily the best way but still seems ok to me.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes i included element in main project, here is just a sample. I update and include element to display validation error in this question too. But if i use normal submit cant display validation error in partal view and partail view open in new page

Comment: @StephenMuecke Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51779944/how-to-display-partial-view-model-errors-when-partial-view-is-in-the-view). I want to keep this condition

Answer (score 0):

As you are dealing with an AJAX callback, you can't do the redirection on server-side. This must be handled on client-side using Javascript.

Examine the response from the server and if it's a redirection then set [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections#JavaScript_redirections) to the received URL.

Comment: You say i should use jquery ajax or javascript?

Comment: Exactly -  if you want to go down the road you described.